# android app can't root but shell can

Tags: android, root

I read lots of websites about how to root an android device and give the app root privileges.
Now I have installed `superuser` app. When I enter `su` in a console to the device then `superuser` comes to ask for rights. This looks fine.

But when I do `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` in my app nothing happens.
Error code is 1, message is `permission denied`. No `superuser` message appears. This looks like my app can't call `su`. Funny: when I let my app call `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -v");` I get a result! (namely the `su` version).

Call to `su` only fails.

What am I missing?
Btw. I added permission `android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER` to the manifest as stated somewhere.
There are so many threads about root privileges, but none of them explains what can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is this CyanogenMod? Look in the settings: you can choose whether to allow apps to request root, and whether to allow adb to do so. You might have got it set to "ADB only". If so, change it to "ADB and apps".

Your `su -V` tells you that you're successfully executing an external program; but `su` itself is refusing to let you become root.

Comment: interesting point however it is 4.2.2, not cyanogen mod. there is no such option :-(
I am getting a java securityexception
Permission Denial: broadcast asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

I am investigation this further but without success so far.

Comment: Hmm, have you tried giving it a command line? Try `...exec("su -c 'id'")` and see if it's any happier with that.

Comment: Btw, that error message sounds as though your SuperUser installation is a bit screwed, There's no such thing as user -1. Does it work with other root apps? (E.g., try AdAway.)

Comment: I got the error! The suid bit on su was not set. I guess that's why su could be started (because world's x permission was set) but it was not allowed to do that broadcast thing afterwards in the name of root.

Comment: OMG this error comes from /system/bin/am not being started with the expected user. Or it should have different rights.

I am playing with that rooting stuff without a really rooted android. This is why I am stepping from one error to the other.

Sorry for the bunch of comments, got to get used to shift-return when I want a line break.